# Change blue selection color for HTML tables that appears on CTRL + left click to select multiple cells (for static website hosting)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, selection

[image]

When one selects something related to a table in Firefox, there are one of a few things that one can get.
I know how to change outline color of editable table cells on focus and text selection color but I don't know how I can change the blue color I still get when I hold down the control key while selecting cells. Does anybody have a hint or know what can I use?

I want to host on a static website service so only CSS, HTML and JS are (the sane?) possible solutions here, out of those I would prefer to be able to set it by just using a bit of CSS similar to how I do it in the following example.

Example HTML:

```
<style>
    td:focus { /* on click on editable cells */
        outline: dashed;
    }
    ::selection { /* on text selection */
        background: red;
    }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">C</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you looking for ::selection?

Comment: I'm literally using ::selection in my example. In the example it changes the background color of text when CTRL is NOT held down.
Fair, I don't use outline in the ::selection part but outline doesn't do anything visible. I want to change the blue color that is around a cell when it has an active selection after it got selected by CTRL + left mouse click (or drag). The color changes to gray when inactive (when I click on a different window for example).

Comment: What I noticed: When I set ui.highlight in about:config of Firefox it does actually change the highlight background highlight color for text AND the color used when table cells are selected via control key + left mouse key... However, that doesn't really tell me anything about the CSS needed to change that on the website.